# Simple Field Calculation In ArcPy

Tags: arcpy

Can some one please let me know how I can do simple field calculation like Copying From "A" to "B" in ArcPy? I have found lots of examples on the web where they all used extra expressions and they were complicated.  What I need is something like ArcMap Gui:

```
B = !A!
```

Updated:
Here is the code I have so far but I am getting error on running this as

> NameError: name 'A' is not defined

```
point_shp = "G:\\Temp\\All_Provinces.shp"
arcpy.AddField_management(point_shp, "B", "TEXT", "", "", "25", "", "NON_NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(point_shp, "B", "A", "PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: can you post one of the more complicated examples?

Answer (score 1):

Optionally, if you wanted the calculate field tool to compute using VB then you could do this:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(point_shp, "B","[A]")
```

That's just if you have an application that calls for visual basic instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it, the A must be wrapped like `"!A!"`

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(point_shp, "B","!A!", "PYTHON_9.3")
```

wow this forum is awesome! so many help!

Answer (score 0):

I would attack this by using an update cursor, though I do not know if that meets your need of simplicity.

```
point_shp = "G:\\Temp\\All_Provinces.shp" 
updateCursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(point_shp)
for row in updateCursor:
    a = row.getValue("name of the "a" field name")
    b = a # --> any manipulations to b can also go here.. example b = a + c  etc... 
          # --> alternatively if you need to do string manipulations you can always make use of specifiers.  such that a = "!%s!" %(a) note:use %d if "a" is a number. This would produce a string "!a!" if you needed it in that format. 
    row.setValue("name of "b" field", b)
    updateCursor.update(row)
```

The above will allow you to get values of field "A", do something to those values if need be and store as b. Then populates field "B" with b.

Note: If field B is not already created you will need to do so...